# Universal method that is called when app goes in background

Tags: android

Is there any universal method that is called when app goes in background ? I dont want to perform the action when the activity is changes just want to perform it when app goes in background i.e.home_screen appears.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using `ActivityLifeCycleCallbacks`:

```
public class LifeCycleCallbacks implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    /**
     * Keeps a count of the activities started.
     */
    private int mActivitiesStarted;
    /**
     * Keeps a count of the activities stopped.
     */
    private int mActivitiesStopped;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        if (mActivitiesStarted == mActivitiesStopped) {
            // This is the session start
        }
        ++mActivitiesStarted;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        ++mActivitiesStopped;
        if ((mActivitiesStarted > 0) && (mActivitiesStarted == mActivitiesStopped)) {
            /* This is session end. We can do things that we need to do when the app
            * session ends, i.e. send tracking info, etc. */
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

    }
}
```

Finally, register your `LifeCycleCallbacks` class with your `Application` class in `onCreate`:

`registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new LifeCycleCallbacks());`